fullscreen video not working in ReactMarkdown with rehypeRaw plugin
I am using React with ReactMarkdown, rehypeRaw, and remarkGfm plugins to render markdown content, and everything works fine except for the video tag. When the video enters fullscreen mode, it exits unexpectedly. I am using the following custom component configuration to render markdown content:
JS File:
<ReactMarkdown
  remarkPlugins={[remarkGfm]}
  rehypePlugins={[rehypeRaw]}
  components={{
    video({ node, src, alt, children }) {
      return <video className='my-3 rounded-md' controls autoPlay src={src} alt={alt}>{children}</video>;
    },
    // my other components
  }}
>
  {post.content}
</ReactMarkdown>

MD File:
<video>
  <source src="/videos/exposed_key_demo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

The issue is that when the video is played and goes into fullscreen mode, it exits fullscreen immediately
I expect the video to stay in fullscreen mode when it's triggered, similar to standard video players.
